# Electrostatic potential of a line charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential, gauss-law

[image]

The answer is C, But I don't know the concept or the method that is used to solve this problem.

Could someone explain the concept in order to solve this type of problem?

Comment: Dimensional analysis?

Comment: What concept? What method? I think what you are asking is, "Can somebody show me how to solve this problem?"

Comment: @JAustin : *Spherical* symmetry? The charge distribution is a circle not a sphere. ... BTW your comment looks like an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every element of charge on the circle can be thought of as a point source at a distance $a$ from the origin. If you look at an infinitesimal charge that occupies an angle $d\theta$, the charge will be $\rm{dQ = \rho ~ a ~d\theta}$.

[image]

The potential due to this charge is of course $dV = \frac{dQ}{4\pi\epsilon_0 a}$. Summing the contribution of all these elements gives you

$$V = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\rho a d\theta}{4\pi\epsilon_0 a} = \frac{2\pi\rho a}{4\pi\epsilon_0 a}=\frac{\rho}{2\epsilon_0}$$